# Django Nested Template Tags

Tags: python, django

I have a custom template tag that accesses a models function. However, I also need the custom template tag to be in a for loop, which requires nested template tags:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% for list in remind_lists %} 
    <h3>{{ list.title }}</h3>
    {% for item in {% get_list_items user.username %} %}
        <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me a TemplateSyntaxError- 'for' statements should use the format 'for x in y': for item in {% get_list_items user.username. Is there anyway I can do this?

custom tag:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_list_items(event_ins, authenticated_user):
    return event_ins.get_list_items(authenticated_user)
```

Comment: Have you loaded the tag at the top of your template? Please post the full error you get.

Comment: Yes I loaded the template tag, and I just posted the full error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't nest tags in this way - but you can assign the output of the tag to a variable that you can then loop over:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
{% for list in remind_lists %} 
    <h3>{{ list.title }}</h3>
    {% get_list_items list user.username as list_items %}
    {% for item in list_items %}
        <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# you can format the text or data in the function itself and return the same to the template


{% for list in remind_lists %} 
    <h3>{{ list.title }}</h3>
    {{ list.id|get_list_items:authenticated_user }} 
{% endfor %}




register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_list_items(event_ins, authenticated_user):
    # you can format the text or data here
    return ...
```