# Pass a static asset to an include in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to pass a static asset to an include i'm using.

The include is formatted like so:

```
{% include "path/to/image_set.html" with img_source=image %}
```

and I want to pass a static asset:

```
{% static 'path/to/background.png' %}
```

to the image source, but I cant nest tags.

Comment: You can just use it in the child template? Or pass a boolean `image_from_static=1` if the source comes from media sometimes and static other times.

Comment: A related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122127/django-nested-template-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the filename and then call the static in the other template.

For example, you have a file called 'hero.png' in your static folder.

You then have a template you want to call that looks like this:

```
<header>
   <img src="{% static filename %}" />
</header>
```

Normally, that image source would be:

```
{% static 'hero.png' %}
```

But in this case you want to use it with a variable.

In that case, you would pass the variable filename into the includes:

```
{% include "hero.html" with filename='hero.png' %}
```